# What is the significance of Southend-on-Sea?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world

When working out the co-ordinates of the 'Convergence' in *Thor: The Dark World*, Erik Selvig claims that "the ancients left us coordinates" in the form of symbolic 'markers'.

Stonehenge is listed as one (makes sense, I suppose), so is Snowdon (a mountain range? How is this an ancient 'marker', but whatever) and this unexplained spot off the coast of Southend-on-Sea, famous for... erm... [the world's longest pleasure pier?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southend-on-Sea) The Leigh-on-Sea [Fishing Festival](http://www.essexinfo.net/leigh-on-sea/events/fishing-festival/)? Being the spiritual home of [comedian Lee Evans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Evans_%28comedian%29)?!

[image: Map of the convergence]

What is its 'historic' significance? It seems a totally arbitrary choice, when Britain is [filled to brimming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neolithic_British_Isles) with neolithic landmarks.

Is this supposed to be an incredibly subtle joke? Or are we missing something?

Comment: Is one of the actors from there? I remember an actor on the Graham Norton Show recently mentioned there was a British reference in their movie - I don't remember which actor/movie but it may have been this one.

Comment: Nope, at least non of the named/featured/starring cast. There are plenty of 'British references' (much of the film being set in England), but there's nothing of note at Southend-On-Sea, it's a very dull place. This is why I thought it might be a joke, albeit an incredibly brief and subtle one.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is from the Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy, where Ford and Arthur see the seafront at Southend when they are rescued by the Heart of Gold. Doubt it's that though.

Comment: Back when Erik Selvig was a young student doing amateur dramatics, he was the toast of Southend-on-Sea, wherever that is.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional: "it's a very dull place" - try saying that loudly in the Slug & Lettuce at 10:45 on a Saturday night, see how far it gets you.

Comment: I don't think there's any significance to it. From what I recall, he goes "Stone Henge", then draws a line - how does he know which direction to even draw it in? The points seem arbitrarily chosen so that the lines intersect at a point that's conveniently right next to where the action is already happening.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, I agree, although he isn't 'discovering' his theory of convergence, he's demonstrating it to convince the others of its merits, so this is just a rushed re-enactment of what he already knows... there's obviously a lot of information undisclosed to the audience, but there still must be *Some* reason (one way or another) why they chose Southend on Sea over anywhere else....

Comment: Do any of the other points occure in the other directions the same distance to Greenwich as Southend-On-Sea?  Being an American, I'm unfamiliar with British geography (please don't hold that against me!) but I would guess some of the points are chosen for their distance either to the other points or to Greenwich not necesarilly any other reason.

Comment: We don't know, but it doesn't make any difference. Selvig talks about points of significance and ancient civilisations leaving markers, and this is highlighted as one of them. Most of the others go un-seen/named, we just see him drawing the lines from them...

Answer (score 3):

If anything, it's most likely a reference to Warren Ellis - he lives in Southend and has written for both the Thor AND Excalibur titles. In fact, if that's the case, that might qualify as an Excalibur reference for your other question.

Answer (score -1):

It's the [Maunsell Forts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maunsell_Forts) probably.

> The Maunsell Forts are armed towers built in the Thames and Mersey estuaries during the Second World War to help defend the United Kingdom. They were operated as army and navy forts, and named after their designer, Guy Maunsell.

Comment: I highly doubt this is the case, they're far too recent.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Well, maybe the British built the forts there for some other reason, and national defence was just a cover. Or maybe the most convenient location for the fort was on top of a lump of rock that happened to have some archaeology on it, the significance of which was not recognised at the time.

Comment: @PaulJohnson If that is the case it would make a decent answer. However, at the moment it does not appear to be the case. If you can find some evidence for this and [edit] it in let me know, I'd be happy to read it.